How to remove crawled pages before they are indexed?
The situation is that we have about 200k pages indexed, and another 600k in a "crawled but not indexed" state in Google Search Console. Our strategy has changed and we no longer want to index a large portion of those unindexed pages.
I know we can export the URLs that are in that list, so we can easily adjust how we serve them, etc.
But what's the correct move – do I just add noindex header to those pages and invoke "Validate Fix" on Google?
A follow up question to this – do the noindex pages count towards our crawl budget?
